# Como autenticar usuário corretamente?

Tags: php, mysql

Bom estou fazendo um sistema de login em php e mysql, ele funciona bem, porém funciona bem até demais. Quando eu tento me logar com o login e senha corretos o arquivo autentication.php autentica-os perfeitamente, por exemplo: login=teste e senha=123. Porém quando eu tento mudar o login, por exemplo: login=TesTE e senha=123; o arquivo autentica normalmente. Como eu corrijo, isso?

O código do autentication.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("connection.php");

    $btnLogin = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnLogin', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if($btnLogin){
        $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        //echo "$user - $password";
        if ((!empty($user)) AND (!empty($password))){
            $result_user = "SELECT id, user, password FROM accounts WHERE user='$user' LIMIT 1";
            $resulted_user = mysqli_query($conn, $result_user);
            if ($resulted_user){
                $row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulted_user);
                if(password_verify($password, $row_user['password'])){
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row_user['id'];
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row_user['user'];
                    }
                    header("Location: /repo/main.php");
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Login or password incorrect";
          header("Location: /repo/index.php");
                }
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Login or password incorrect";
      header("Location: /repo/index.php");
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Page Not Found";
    header("Location: /repo/index.php");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na query feita ao SQL, pois, por padrão, essa busca será case insensitive, [conforme consta na documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).

Para resolver esse problema, conforme sugerido na própria documentação, deve-se adicionar um collate à query. Qual deles adicionar depende do seu caso e pode ser o mesmo que já é usado, mas case sensitive.

Ex:

```sql
SELECT id, user, password FROM accounts WHERE user COLLATE latin1_general_cs = '$user' LIMIT 1
```

---

Honestamente, não recomendo a ninguém que desenvolva código de autenticação/autorização a não ser que queira aprender a fundo sobre o tema. Caso o objetivo seja ter este recurso e não o aprendizado (e para isso seria importante aprofundar-se muito no assunto), recomendava procurar uma solução já pronta ou verificar como é feito em alguns projetos grandes e open source. Para isso, vc pode procurar ver um framework ou o Wordpress, por exemplo.